# Is there a GUI way to import chain data and what would be best practice?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, import, chaindata

I am trying to copy over chain data from one machine to another. Is there a way in the GUI to do this?
Is there a how to/best practice for putting 300+ GB of chain data on new machine and launching ethereum wallet successfully? 
Do I launch ethereum wallet first then move chain data into file created? What would be proper steps to do this? I have tried but gotten 'can not connect to node' error

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the chain file first. Then you start your wallet. It will see that you already have a chain and start from there.

Comment: Okay, so create file structure and only have chain data without 'current', 'lock', 'log' etc. etc?

Comment: That did not work, still getting can not connect to node...

Answer (score 0):

Find your keystore file, its a json formatted file.

Install Mist on the other machine, find the location where geth is installed startup geth 1st using the --light or --fast parameters.

Move the keystore file over to the same location on the machine.